# docker swarm uses ingress as the default IP other than the default overlay network

Tags: mysql, galera, swarm

When I use docker deploy a docker-compose.yml with all my stack. It creates a default overlay network.

ac4ole1w87ws        ingress                overlay             swarm
vcl2s9otd2qx        stack_default          overlay             swarm

The issue is the containers of the mysql galera cluster is using the ingress 10.255.0.* as the main ip address, not the 10.0.0.* in stack_default.

so the wsrep_cluster_address looks like a mess up, I do not know why some are coming from the stack_default, some are coming from the ingress.
10.255.0.3,10.0.0.5,10.0.0.6

Sometimes 10.0.0.5 could not talk to 10.255.0.3 (different networks)

I know I can set a networks for each container but that is too many to set(my stack has more than 20). Any better way?

Comment: Can you make your docker-compose.yml and galera config files public? Otherwise it's no possible to detect the error.  
General: the ingress network is only used be the manager nodes to distribute tasks to other nodes. You galera nodes should not talk to IP-addresses, they must talk to the services by name, which defined in your stack file. E.g. when deploying a service named `some-redis`, other services from the same stack can reach the service by requsting `some-redis` (e.g. `ping some-redis`). the DNS feature is the key concept from docker swarm mode.